# How to change properties of objects in blender with python

Tags: python, blender

I am currently using the game engine in Blender. I was wondering how can I change the properties of an object via script, like position, rotation, color, and change the related variables in the objects.

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]
scene.Cube.diffuse_color = [0]=red [1]=green [2]=blue
```

In the example above I tried to change the color of a Cube, but it fails with the error "Cannot assign to literal". How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

### A couple of suggestions

1. Before starting to code in Blender you have to be sure of what you are doing because unless it is going to become hard to find a solution to your problem.
2. Always look at [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/introduction.html).
3. Blender has a hidden console that you can show up by dragging and dropping the higher part of the UI; every time you do something in the UI (move an object, change a color,...), the corresponding Python command is displayed here:
   [image]

### About your question

The following is a simple snippet to show you how to change the color of the default Cube in Blender:

```
import bpy
activeObject = bpy.context.active_object #Set active object to variable
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialName") #set new material to variable
activeObject.data.materials.append(mat) #add the material to the object
bpy.context.object.active_material.diffuse_color = (1, 0, 0) #change color
```

You can also access an object's transformations through the relevant properties (location, rotation_euler - for Euler XYZ rotations, and scale) this way:

```
>>> object.location
Vector((-2.609607696533203, -3.618044137954712, 1.8581657409667969))

>>> object.rotation_euler
Euler((-0.6668576598167419, 0.697817325592041, -1.8853096961975098), 'XYZ')

>>> object.scale
Vector((1.2768771648406982, 1.4246054887771606, 0.6418209075927734))
```

Hope this is a good hint for you to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error you get is because the code you show is not valid python code, to change the color value, you need to have the index (the `[0]`) attached to the property name and the value to assign goes on the other side of the `=` sign.

```
color[0] = 0.1
```

It is possible to assign the same value to several properties in one line -

```
color[0] = color[1] = color[2] = 0.2
```

You can also assign all four values (color includes an alpha) to the color property by using a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) -

```
red = blue = green = alpha = 0.2

color = (red, green, blue, alpha)
```

Now on to what you are trying to do -

There are two ways to access blenders data, [bpy](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/#application-modules) is only used for accessing data while you are modeling, texturing etc.

When the game engine is running bpy is not available, you need to use [bge](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/#game-engine-modules) to access any data from scripts you assign to a python controller.

To get what you are trying to work, first enable object color for the material, you can find this under [options in the material settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/options.html). With this enabled you can adjust the objects color property -

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

own.color[0] = 0.2 # red
own.color[1] = 0.3 # green
own.color[2] = 0.4 # blue
```

It is possible to access other objects, you use [`getCurrentScene()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.getCurrentScene) to get the current scene which has the list of objects,

```
scn = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
enemy = scn.objects['enemy']
```

You can find sample code in many of the API pages for [game engine types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.html) and will find [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask blender questions.